# How to create an application that starts the service after boot up sequences are finished?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to create an app that starts the service after rebooted, but I do not want to show the UI–just like the service run in the background silently. I can create it,but after rebooted the application crashes. Because, MainActivity had not launched and I don't want to launch any activity. How do I solve this problem?

My manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.galleryapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".CameraEventReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

     <receiver android:name="com.galleryapp.RebootDeviceReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
     </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".BackgroundService"
        android:exported="true" />

</application>
```

And my receiver class:

```
public class RebootDeviceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
       context.startService(serviceIntent);

   }
}
```

Comment: post the crash log.

Comment: I don't know how to get crash log. Because the problem occurs after rebooted and I can not run the application during reboot. But I explained under the answer of Ridcully you can see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a BroadcastReceiver and register it in your Manifest file.

```
<receiver android:name="your.package.BootCompletedReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

From your BroadcastReceiver you can then start a service. For example, in my code I'm using a `JobIntentService`.

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent msgIntent = new Intent(context, MyJobIntentService.class);
        msgIntent.setAction(MyJobIntentService.ACTION_RESCHEDULE);
        MyJobIntentService.enqueueWork(context, msgIntent);
    }
}
```

If you want your service to run for a longer amount of time, you need to run it as a foreground service, at least for newer Android versions.

Comment: I already defined it. You can see in the question "... I can create it,but after rebooted the application crashes. ... ". The problem is, how can I run background service without any activity / UI.

Comment: Can you run the service with this code without any UI?

Comment: Yes, a service never has a UI -- except for mentioned foreground services, which need to show a notification, so that the user knows that there is something running (and eating up battery or monitoring him etc.)

Comment: I know I tried foreground service before this. But, when the reboot is completed the application crashes. Because there is a main activity but I don't want run main activity. If mainactivity has not run then the intent will be null.

Comment: Which intent is null? The intent passed to onReceive? You can check that: `if (!Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
         return;
        }`

Comment: It will return null at everytime. Because, I didn't and I don't want run the mainactivity after rebooted

Comment: I do not understand what returns null. You don't need any activity for this scenario. Perhaps add some of your code to the question.

Comment: To get crash log after your app crashed, just go to LogCat in AndroidStudio and select 'No Filters' in the dropdown at the far right, select 'Error' from the log-level dropdown and search for 'com.galleryapp'. I suppose, the problem is that you're starting a background service, which you are not allowed to.

Comment: @Ridicully Yes I got the crash log and the Error is that I am starting a background service, which I am not allowed to. Do you know how can I allow to the start service from service?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you will have to run yoir service as a foreground service. Or, depending on what your service is doing, you can perhaps use WorkManager (still in Beta)

Comment: Can I use the IntentService or JobIntentService?

Comment: I am using a JobIntentService in my example. This works for a short task (like rescheduling alarms etc.). If your service needs to run for long time you have to use a foreground service.

Comment: Okey. Thank you for your suggestion and your interest Ridicully.